# EDT for the positive integer numbers in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++

I created integer EDT for "Item Number".

Which "Extends" type should I use in properties for positive int numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the EDT `PositiveNumber`.

But if you are making a new type for identification purposes, you may leave the `Extends` property blank, and set `AllowNegative` to No. Beware that you will be limited to 9 digits for `int` and 18 for `int64`.